# Matlab plotting a decaying exponential and curve fit to find peaks

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot data from a csv file, I have successfully uploaded the csv as an array for each column.  I'm then trying to find the peaks of each column, I need to then plot the peaks for each to a time constant (tau).  I have been getting an error that I need to have the same size vectors to plot. I'm also trying to plot all sets of data on one plot and have a curve fit for each.
Please help me out!
code is below

```
Array=csvread("D:\Grad Lab\NMR\Data\T1 Data\compiledT1nolabel.csv");
tau = Array(:,1);
Water= Array(:,2);
Mineral_Oil = Array(:,3);
Glycerol = Array(:,4);
CuSO4_1=Array(:,5);
CuSO4_2=Array(:,6);
CuSO4_3=Array(:,7);
CuSO4_4=Array(:,8);
CuSO4_5=Array(:,9);

pks1 = findpeaks(Water);
pks2 = findpeaks(Mineral_Oil);
pks3 = findpeaks(Glycerol);
pks4 = findpeaks(CuSO4_1);
pks5 = findpeaks(CuSO4_2);
pks6 = findpeaks(CuSO4_3);
pks7 = findpeaks(CuSO4_4);
pks8 = findpeaks(CuSO4_5);

plot(pks1,tau)
```

Comment: Without your data or more details about the specific and complete error message, it's hard to know what's wrong. Please produce a [mcve] which illustrates the issue and [edit] it into the question

Comment: Most likely, ```pks1``` and ```tau``` have different sizes (number of elements).

Comment: I'd suggest to review the title of the question: it's more about plotting and using ```findpeaks``` properly than it is about exponentials...

Comment: `findpeaks` returns a *dynamic* number of elements in the array, that is , it depends on the data. If you wanted to plot the peaks vs the *corresponding* values of `tau`  you should do something on the lines of `[pks1, idx1] = findpeaks(Water)` followed by `plot(pks1, tau(idx1))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `pks` vectors and the corresponding data arrays you are trying to plot don't have the same size: calling the `plot` function on vectors of different sizes produces the error.

In the sample script below, `data` contains a bunch of values. Invoking `findpeaks` with two outputs (i.e. `locs` and `pks`) allows both the  locations and peak values to be stored. Now we can use `locs` and `pks` with `plot` to mark the peaks as follows:

```
data = [25 8 15 5 6 10 10 3 1 20 7];
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(data);
plot(data); hold
plot(locs, pks, 'd')
```

produces the following plot:

[image]

Alternatively, if you are just interested in plotting, you could use

```
findpeaks(data)
```

without any output: it will produce a plot like this:

[image]

For the OP's specific case, I modified his script as follows (just covered one set of peaks, the pattern should be clear):

```
Array=csvread("D:\Grad Lab\NMR\Data\T1 Data\compiledT1nolabel.csv");
tau = Array(:,1);
Water = Array(:,2);

[pks1, locs1] = findpeaks(Water);

figure
plot(tau, Water); hold on;
plot(tau(locs1), pks1, 'd');
```